# Null Pointer Exception in Unit test in spock

Tags: java, unit-testing, spock

i Have a class "ComparisonService" with the following fn-

```
public HashMap <String, Map<String, Object>> fetchTableData(DataSource dataSource, List<Object> tableInfo){
    table.setTableInfo(tableInfo);
    HashMap<String, Map<String, Object>> records = table.fetchData(dataSource);
    System.out.println(records.size());
    return records;
}
```

Here table is an Object of other class Table

I am writing a spock test for this Method-

```
class ComparisonSpec extends spock.lang.Specification{
Table table=Mock()
def DataSource dataSource
def List<Object> tableInfo=[1]
def setup()
{
    //def DataSource dataSource 
}
def "first function"()
{
    given:
    def ComparisonService comparison= new ComparisonService()
    when:
    comparison.fetchTableData(dataSource,tableInfo)
    then:
    1*table.setTableInfo(_ as String)>>true
    1*table.fetchData(_ as DataSource)
}
```

When I run it I get

> null pointer Exception at
>   comparison.fetchTableData(dataSource,tableInfo).

why is that so.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Possibly because `def DataSource dataSource` means your datasource is `null`. Try instantiating or mocking it as well

Comment: I have tried that by changing "def DataSource dataSource" to "DataSource dataSource=Mock() " but still Null Pointer Exception is coming.

Comment: You create `table` as a mock, but you never pass it on to your `comparison` instance. Furthermore, `1*table.fetchData(_ as DataSource)` needs to return at least an empty map or `records.size()` will throw an NPE as well.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so a couple of points I can see:

**First** `def DataSource dataSource`
You are trying to statically and dynamically type your variable. This should be either:

- Static: `DataSource dataSource`
- Dynamic: `def dataSource`

**Second**
You declare the variable `dataSource` but never initialise it. Either in the test or the setup you need: 
`dataSource = <what ever data source is>`

Answer (score -1):

The reason may be the variable of records is null, you should mock for records.

Comment: your answer in its current state is more a comment than an answer, can you give a code example of the solution you have in mind?